# Far relationships in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder, laravel-5.8

My database structure looks like this:

```
User
    id - integer

user_user_group
    user_id - integer
    user_group_id - integer

meeting_user_group
    user_group_id - integer
    meeting_id - integer

meeting_mails
    meeting_id - integer
    sent - boolean
    date - date

meetings
    id - integer
```

I have a user from whom I need to get the meeting_mails where `sent == false` and `date == today`.
Is there a smart way to do this in Laravel, or do I have to write an ugly SQL query by hand?
For performance reasons, I would like to make as little as possible with collections or arrays and let the database do as much as possible.
I'm using Laravel version 5.8

Comment: Do you have relationships set up? If so, you could use [`hasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

Comment: HasManyThrough won't work for this. It's only through one other table and not through two or more other tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [this](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) package now.
It is an easy way to build such relationships.